# Physical Multirobot AMCL Not Able To Transform To /map

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, namespaces, tf-tree, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get multiple physical Turtlebot3's functioning with AMCL with namespaces.
My setup works perfectly fine with the Gazebo simulations, but moving it to the real thing causes issues.

After running AMCL I get the error:

```
No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1600396510.205957 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /tb3_0/scan topic.
```

I have looked at the solution found here: https://answers.ros.org/question/325980/amcl-no-laser-scan-received/
But I couldn't seem to see what I am doing wrong.

There was also another source that I found here: https://github.com/wachlinn/mrc_hw8/blob/master/launch/amcl_tb0.launch

but this seemed to have the same setup that I had.

My steps are as follows:

1. On the Turtlebot launch `ROS_NAMESPACE=tb3_0 roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch multi_robot_name:="tb3_0"`
2. On the Linux workstation (and all following steps) launch `ROS_NAMESPACE=tb3_0 roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_remote.launch multi_robot_name:=tb3_0`
3. `roslaunch voronoi_node_generator map_provider.launch` (see launch files below)
4. `roslaunch basic_swarm swarm_amcl.launch multi_robot_name:=tb3_0`

Here are the two launch files from steps 3

```
<launch>
  <arg name="map_name"  default="dining"/>
  <node pkg="map_server" name="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find voronoi_node_generator)/maps/$(arg map_name).yaml"/>
</launch>
```

and 4:

```
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="scan_topic"        default="scan"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_x"    default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y"    default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a"    default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="multi_robot_name"  doc="User assigned robot namespace."/>
  <arg name="global_frame_id"   default="map"/>
  <arg name="init_with_global"  default="false"/>

  <!-- AMCL -->
  <group ns="$(arg multi_robot_name)">
    <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl">

      <param name="min_particles"             value="500"/>
      <param name="max_particles"             value="3000"/>
      <param name="kld_err"                   value="0.02"/>
      <param name="update_min_d"              value="0.20"/>
      <param name="update_min_a"              value="0.20"/>
      <param name="resample_interval"         value="1"/>
      <param name="transform_tolerance"       value="0.5"/>
      <param name="recovery_alpha_slow"       value="0.00"/>
      <param name="recovery_alpha_fast"       value="0.00"/>
      <param name="initial_pose_x"            value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
      <param name="initial_pose_y"            value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
      <param name="initial_pose_a"            value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
      <param name="gui_publish_rate"          value="50.0"/>

      <remap from="scan"                      to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
      <param name="laser_max_range"           value="3.5"/>
      <param name="laser_max_beams"           value="180"/>
      <param name="laser_z_hit"               value="0.5"/>
      <param name="laser_z_short"             value="0.05"/>
      <param name="laser_z_max"               value="0.05"/>
      <param name="laser_z_rand"              value="0.5"/>
      <param name="laser_sigma_hit"           value="0.2"/>
      <param name="laser_lambda_short"        value="0.1"/>
      <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
      <param name="laser_model_type"          value="likelihood_field"/>

      <param name="odom_model_type"           value="diff"/>
      <param name="odom_alpha1"               value="0.1"/>
      <param name="odom_alpha2"               value="0.1"/>
      <param name="odom_alpha3"               value="0.1"/>
      <param name="odom_alpha4"               value="0.1"/>
      <param name="tf_prefix"                 value="$(arg multi_robot_name)"/>
      <param name="odom_frame_id"             value="$(arg multi_robot_name)/odom"/>
      <param name="base_frame_id"             value="$(arg multi_robot_name)/base_footprint"/>
      <param name="global_frame_id"           value="$(arg global_frame_id)"/>
      <remap from="initialpose"               to="initialpose"/>
      <remap from="amcl_pose"                 to="amcl_pose"/>
      <remap from="particlecloud"             to="particlecloud"/>
      <remap from="map"                       to="/map"/>
      <remap from="map_metadata"              to="/map_metadata"/>
      <param name="use_map_topic" value="true"/>
    </node>

    <node name="init_localize" pkg="basic_swarm" type="init_localize.py" if="$(arg init_with_global)"/>
  </group>

</launch>
```

And lastly it looks as though my tf and node trees are fine:
[image: /map is not being used]

[image: everything seems to be in order]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361822/physical-multirobot-amcl-not-able-to-transform-to-/map/) by [cwillia109](https://answers.ros.org/users/51647/cwillia109/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2020-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-17**:
Well you tf tree is not exactly fine because you are missing your map frame right? And just to verify, you did `rostopic echo /tb3_0/scan` and you find that the data is in fact being published in the `tb3_0/base_scan` frame?

**Comment by [cwillia109](https://answers.ros.org/users/51647/cwillia109/) on 2020-09-17**:
@JackB Thanks for the response!
Indeed. I get some laser readings, and the frame_id field from the message is "base_scan"

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-18**:
The frame_id field for the laser scan  should be `/tb3_0/base_scan` shouldn't it?

**Comment by [cwillia109](https://answers.ros.org/users/51647/cwillia109/) on 2020-09-18**:
@JackB From my understanding, it is. `base_scan` is the name, but judging by the tf_tree, it still has the `tb3_0` tf prefix. When you load up a situation like this. should the scan topic include the tf_prefix in the frame_id?

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-18**:
When you echo the `/tb3_0/scan` topic, there should be a field in the message header call `frame_id`. The value of the frame_id should be `/tb3_0/base_scan`. If the frame_id in the header message is not `/tb3_0/base_scan` then it will not know how to transform the scan into your robots reference frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @JackB I was able to find the issue. Everything is set up correctly in the launch files. The only issues was when calling `turtlebot3_robot.launch`.

Taken from the instructions: `ROS_NAMESPACE=tb3_0 roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch multi_robot_name:="tb3_0" set_lidar_frame_id:="tb3_0/base_scan"` was the correct way of calling it. Looking at the tf_tree it, already looked as though the lidar frame was tb3_0/base_scan, but it was not. This step turned out to be absolutely crucial.

---

Originally posted by [cwillia109](https://answers.ros.org/users/51647/cwillia109/) with karma: 49 on 2020-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-19**:
So happy I could help!